# How can i put condition on button based on DataGridView in C#?

Tags: c#

[image: DataGridView]

Hi everyone please anyone can help me :

As shows the picture i have a **datagridview** i wanna add a condition on the first button:
if **selected rows** their **second column** "Fournisseur" **Value aren't the same** in my case for example "Tramauto" and "Diraoui" dont execute the function in the **button :** "passer la commande" but show a box of message.

```
     private void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
```

Comment: If a user selects three Rows and only two are equal? -- Whatever logic you have, loop the `SelectedRows` collection of your DGV and compare the Cells' value at `Columns["Fournisseur"]`

Comment: No Mr. Jimi i want all selected rows to have the same value of colums["Fournisseur"]